# Removing From Super Layer crashes application after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

Hello I am working with `CAShapeLayer` and `CGPath`. I am drawing jigsaw and adding to `scrollview`.I put reload button to check performance. When i am reloading,i am removing all previous layers from `scrollview`. And after some time it is crashing.

Zombie shows me cause of removing layers,that's the issue. Is that anything wrong in code?
Here it is :

```
NSArray* layerArray = [[self.scrollView.layer sublayers]copy];

    for (int i = 0; i < layerArray.count; i++) {
        A3JigsawView* aJigsawView = [layerArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [aJigsawView removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    self.scrollView.layer.sublayers = nil;

    prevWidth = 0;
    prevHeight = 0;
```

Please help me.Thanking you.

Comment: could you pls attach the stack log when the app crash?

Comment: it is not showing anything...

Comment: Ok than... so I would check that everything is done in the main thread, maybe you can try dispatching this code in the main_queue

Comment: Before you reload, you may want to release your copy of the sublayers: `layerArray = nil;` Assuming that immediately after the code you show that you add the layers again. Don't know if that will do it, as the layerArray would get released anyway after your method exits - assuming you are using ARC.

Answer (score 5):

It's `self.scrollView.layer.sublayers = nil`. Indiscriminately removing all sublayers causes nasty crashes in iOS 7, which can occur much later in the program's execution. I have tested this thoroughly using both `rootLayer.sublayers = nil` and `[rootLayer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]`. There must be a system-created layer that's getting messed up.

You have to keep your own array of layers and remove them yourself:

```
[myArrayOfLayersIAddedMyself makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to keep track of the layers which have been drawn on the respective view.
For example :
    NSMutableArray *listOfCAShapeLayer;

```
UIBezierPath *pathToDraw = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[pathToDraw moveToPoint:startPoint];
[pathToDraw addLineToPoint:endPoint];
[pathToDraw stroke];

CAShapeLayer  *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [pathToDraw CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

[self. listOfCAShapeLayer addObject:shapeLayer];

[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Now we had our CAShapeLayer saved in array self. listOfCAShapeLayer
We can have a condition checked where ever we want the erase function
like :
Bool bIsErase;
if (bISErase == YES) then execute the following:

```
[self. listOfCAShapeLayer enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

CAShapeLayer *sl = obj;
[sl removeFromSuperlayer];
```

}];

I hope this helps you now.